# Refresh currently selected tab on Ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, tabs, jquery-1.8

I have a few tabs, populated from a database. Each tab contains a partial view, also populated from the database. When someone adds something to one of the collections that these partials represent, I want it to refresh the tab content, to reflect the change.

```
function addNewRequest(arForm) {
    username = $(".ui-tabs-selected").attr("id");
    currentUser = document.getElementById("currUser").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/submitAdvisoryRequestForm',
        type: 'POST',
        data: arForm.serialize() + "&username=" + username + "&currUser=" + currentUser,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == "true") {
                $("#users").tabs("load", $('#users .ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)').index() - 1);
                dialog.dialog("close");
            } else {
                alert(response);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError); }
    });

}
```

So by my understanding, if the ajax call is successful, it would attempt to load the tab at the currently selected index. I have watched the expression used to grab the selected tab index, and as far as I can tell, it works, even if maybe slightly hacky.

The code that should refresh the tab, `$("#users").tabs("load", $('#users .ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)').index() - 1);`, does nothing. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't a question

Comment: Please show your HTML. & your code initializing the tabs.

Comment: My initial thoughts are your `url` should be either `./Home...` or `/Home...` as opposed to just `Home...` also I don't think you need to `-1` on the index.

Comment: The URL works fine, it's just the `'load'` method in JQuery that isn't working. Without the `-1`, it returns an index which isn't zero-based, and that's not very useful :)

To clarify, I can get the AJAX function to return successfully, I just can't refresh the tab content.

Comment: Why the curly bracket at the end of this statement: `$("#users").tabs("load", $('#users .ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)').index() - 1});`?

Comment: Typo, it isn't there in the implementation I've been testing. Apologies.

Comment: If you stick `console.log($('#users .ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)').index() - 1));` inside the `if` statement, does it log the correct tab index to the console?

Comment: Not with the extra bracket ;) but yes, it does.

Comment: Perhaps caching is an issue? Try adding the options to the `$("#users").tab` definition: `cache: false, ajaxOptions: {cache: false}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58889/discussion-between-richard-cane-and-mccannf).

Comment: @RobSchmuecker sorry I didn't even see that comment, which HTML were you referring to? The HTML of the partial or the HTML of the page that initialises the tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F**kadoodle-doo, I figured it out. Because JQueryUI is lame and only lets you refresh AJAX loaded content, it's easier to just replace the HTML of the currently selected tab's div.

JQuery code:

```
function addNewRequest(arForm) {
    username = $(".ui-tabs-selected").attr("id");
    currentUser = document.getElementById("currUser").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/submitAdvisoryRequestForm',
        type: 'POST',
        data: arForm.serialize() + "&username=" + username + "&currUser=" + currentUser,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $('#users .ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)').html(response);
                dialog.dialog("close");
            } else {
                alert(response);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError); }
    });
}
```

And as a response, throw the partial view at it.

```
public ActionResult submitAdvisoryRequestForm(BCRTAdvisoryRequest newRequest, string username, string currUser)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var ar = new AdvisoryRequestsLogic();
        if (ar.addAdvisoryRequest(newRequest) > 0)
            return PartialView("_userAdvisoryRequests", ar.getUserAdvisoryRequests(username));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hah! Glad you sorted it! Amazingly you are now showing code that should have perhaps been in the question?!  BTW jQueryUI is far from lame, since by virtue of the (open source) fact that you are using it,  at least vindicates itself somewhat! I don't agree with your answer though.  jQuery itself (which is the foundation of jQueryUI), enables you to load content into ***any*** element of your choosing. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Ah, you mean the controller code? I figured it wasn't really important, as long as you knew that I was returning a partial view as the content of the tab. Also, is .html() dissimilar to .load()? Maybe I should change it to "JQuery 1.8 is lame" haha

Comment: Yes, `.html()` sets the html whereas `.load()` loads it from a URL.